# Variable assignment not working with Bash -s and heredoc

Tags: bash, shell, heredoc

When I run the following, `$ echo 'ASD=123; echo $ASD hi' | bash -s`, the output is exactly what I expect, `123 hi`. But when I use a heredoc like so:

```
$ bash -s <<EOF
ASD=123; echo $ASD hi
EOF
```

The output is `hi`, which is not what I expect. If I add single quotes around `$ASD`, it prints  `hi`. Why is the variable assignment not working when I use a heredoc?

Comment: The variable is being expanded by the original shell. You need to use `<<'EOF'` to prevent this.

Comment: That works, thanks! I missed that info in the bash docs.